# How can I trigger a job with a manual click OR a commit message

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a job (deploy to production) that we generally manually click after checking that build on staging. However, very occasionally we have an issue that we've accidentally deployed and want to get a fix out ASAP. In those case we run the tests locally (much faster) and put `[urgent-fix]` in our commit message to stop the tests running in CI (skipping straight to Docker image build and staging deploy).

What we'd like to do is if we put `[urgent-fix]` it automatically triggers the production deploy (usually a `when: manual` step). Can we achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you can use a combination of the [only:variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables) syntax and `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` predefined variable.

A rough idea (untested):

```
.deploy_production: &deploy_production
  stage: deploy production
  script:
    - echo "I'm deploy production here"
  tags:
    - some special tag

deploy::manual:
  << *deploy_production
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

deploy:urgent_fix:
  << *deploy_production
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~/[urgent-fix]/
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! We use templated portions already so I should have thought of that!

Answer (score 2):

**As of GitLab v12.3** (~September 2019) GitLab comes with ["Flexible Rules for CI Build config"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/29011). The feature is intended to replace the `only/except` functionality and is fully documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

With `rules:` you can now fully influence the `when:` behaviour of your job based on various conditions (in contrast to `only/except:` which forced you to create separate jobs for situations like the one described in the OP; see accepted answer).

For example you can do:

```
deploy:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /urgent-fix/'
      when: on_success
    - when: manual # default fallback
  script:
    - sh deploy.sh
```

One thing to highlight is that in the above example I used `$CI_COMMIT_TITLE` instead of `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` (see [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)) to avoid the string "urgent-fix" reoccuring in a commit message automatically assembled in the course of a `git merge`, which would then accidentally retrigger the job.

Disclaimer: Please be aware that the new `rules:` feature stands in conflict with `only/except:` and thus requires you to remove `only/except:` occurences. Also, please note that `rules:` should only be used in combination with `workflow:` (read the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules)) to [avoid unwanted "detached" pipelines being triggered](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/34756).